# Accessing and coloring specific lanes based on traffic conditions

Tags: here-api

I'm currently working on a school project where we are using the HERE JS API as well as the iOS SDK. 
We are trying to color roads based on traffic conditions. We are receiving real time sensor data from multiple sensors placed in a small city.
After reading the API documentation we started to draw polylines in different colors like this:

[HERE MAP colored roads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdRC9.jpg)

However, the polylines are only coloring the middle of the road as those were the geopoints we were able to receive through routing. So we can't separate between lanes right now. 
Isn't it possible to access the lanes and change their color like where the arrows in the image are pointing at?

Or do we have to manually provide the geopoints for each lane and draw a polyline? But then it looks kind of ugly with the already colored lanes by HERE...

I'd really appreciate any help! Can't seem to find anything regarding that in the documentation (which is very confusing imo)!

Comment: Can you please help to explain more that -  Do you want to show the traffic flow of a road in both the direction or the only direction in which the current vehicle is moving ?traffic here (developer.here.com/documentation/map-tile/topics/resource-traffic-tile-intro.html) API support various traffic coverage

Comment: The point is, that we have our own traffic data. We just want to color specific lanes based on that.
So we are not interested in the HERE traffic flow as we already turned on the traffic overlay. 
So I've looked into the tile documentation but it just let's you request images (tiles) of specific areas, right? But we are building an interactive map.

Answer (score 0):

To add custom polylines for a lane, geopoints need to be provided. More information on custom object can be referenced at :

**developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics/objects.html
developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics/spatials.html**

For more clarity in the map, MAP image API provides the different views for the map rendering.

**developer.here.com/documentation/map-image/topics/examples-map.html**

Comment: As you can see in the picture, I‘ve already drawn polylines. I just want to change the color of the already  green lanes provided by the Here Traffic MapScheme. Is that possible?